# Есть ли право на запись файла?

Tags: c#

Есть файл, точнее - его полный путь к файлу. Можно ли узнать, есть ли право на запись файла?

Comment: да - попробовать открыть его на запись. если не упадет - право есть

Comment: Файл может быть занят и я тоже получу исключение. Нет никакого метода для проверки?

Comment: Единственный надежный способ — попытаться получить доступ и обрабатывать исключение. Посмотрите обсуждения в английской версии: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net)

Comment: Вы не можете надёжно узнать, возможен ли доступ к файлу, так как **права могут измениться после вашего опроса**. Просто работайте с файлом как ни в чём ни бывало, и ловите исключения.

Comment: VladD, права могут изменяться после опроса, но это весьма частный случай и имеет место с сетевыми ресурсами... В моем варианте это исключено. Файлы хранятся локально и мне нужно знать имеет ли доступ на чтение и запись текущий пользователь к данному файлу или нет.

Answer (score -1):

VladD вам сказал правильно на счет "права могут измениться после вашего опроса"

Однако всё-таки бывают случаи, когда нужно проверить до и после(Например подождать, что другая программа что-то доделала). На такой случай можно воспользоваться:

```
 static bool CheckIfFileIsBeingUsed(string fileName)
 {
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {

        }
    }

    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Вот таким нехитрым методом можно проверить, что файл занят и например подождать до удаления:

```
  while (CheckIfFileIsBeingUsed(file))
     Thread.Sleep(200);
  File.Delete(file);
```

Comment: А почему бы не делать в цикле сразу `File.Delete`?

Comment: я лишь кодом иллюстрировал комментарий "Единственный надежный способ — попытаться получить доступ и обрабатывать исключение. ", и показал как можно использовать этот самый код. 
Т.е. задача проверить, а не удалить.